# How can I create input element that takes multiple strings with NG-Zorro?

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I would like to create NG-ZORRO input element that takes multiple string and create array object of it in JSON format

Thank you!

I tried to create NG-ZORRO. Component

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it might be more suitable to use the [`<nz-select>`](https://ng-zorro.gitee.io/components/select/en) component:

#### HTML

```html
<nz-select
    [nzMaxTagCount]="3"
    [nzMaxTagPlaceholder]="tagPlaceHolder"
    nzMode="multiple"
    nzPlaceHolder="Please select"
    [(ngModel)]="listOfSelectedValue"
  >
  <nz-option *ngFor="let item of listOfOption" [nzLabel]="item" [nzValue]="item"></nz-option>
</nz-select>

<ng-template #tagPlaceHolder let-selectedList>and {{ selectedList.length }} more selected</ng-template>
```

#### TS

```
listOfOption: string[] = [];
listOfSelectedValue = ['a10', 'c12'];

ngOnInit(): void {
  const children: string[] = [];
  for (let i = 10; i < 36; i++) {
    children.push(`${i.toString(36)}${i}`);
  }
  this.listOfOption = children;
}
```